# Checking network connection and running a program based off result

Tags: python

I am writing  a program that will test for an active network connection, then run our software downloader if there is. If there is an update ready to download in the downloader it will automatically download and install said update.

```
import urllib3
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess


def run_downloader():
    return subprocess.Popen(['C:\ProgramFiles\PrecisionOSTech\Education\POSTdownloader.exe'])

def internet_on():

   if urllib3.urlopen('http://216.58.192.142', timeout=1):
    return True
   else:
      urllib3.URLError
   return False
   if internet_on == True:
    run_downloader()
```

The expectation is to have the program test for an active connection and return either true or false. If true, then it should run the downloader.

Currently, the program runs with no errors but does not run the downloader upon completion. I can only imagine that the internet_on(): method is not returning true as I am wanting. If I run the subprocess.Popen line outside of the method, the downloader will start as planned.

Any assistance is appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: I see two errors here, first when trying to throw error use raise and Error object not the class. Second the if internet_on == True is in separate function?

Comment: If internet_on == True is in the same function, are my indents incorrect? lol I am pretty new to all of this.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
import urllib.request
from subprocess import Popen
import subprocess


def run_downloader():
    return subprocess.Popen(['C:\ProgramFiles\PrecisionOSTech\Education\POSTdownloader.exe'])

def ispageresponding():
    response_status_code = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com").getcode()
    return response_status_code == 200:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if ispageresponding() == True:
        run_downloader()
```

Note that internet connection function is called in the if statement and is not inside the same function. Also if you are using python3 you should use urllib.request lib.